# Is that Possible to move a uilabel in navigationbar from left to right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uilabel, uinavigationbar

In my `UIViewController` I am using `UILabel` for navigation title in xib. But text is too long so I need a animation there.Some thing like  a left to right moving `UILabel` ?

Is that possible?
I saw this code but this is for moving one point to another point .
Here `UILabel` name is "label"

```
  float newX = 90.0f;
float newY = 101.0f;

[UIView transitionWithView:label
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^(void) {
                    label.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // Do nothing
                }];
```

Comment: Have you tried adding that UILabel to a UISCrollView? Maybe you can offset the scrollBy with an animation instead?

Comment: i didnt understand what u said

Comment: Instead of initializing your UIBarButtonItem with UIlabel, init it with an UIScrollView that has a your UILabel as a subview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want `marquee` effect that will move each character in label to right.

Here is a way to do that.

First set `NSTimer` in `viewDidAppear:` method to call a method `animateLabel` with with specified time interval as shown below :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(animateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Then define a method that will get label text and reset it to new text. This method is called every 0.4 seconds and give you the marquee effect you want.

```
- (void)animateLabel:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    int labelSize = label.text.length; 
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@", [label.text characterAtIndex:labelSize - 1], [label.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, labelSize - 1)]];
}
```

P.S. : I have not seen such marquee effect on navigation title. I have seen some popular apps where, if label is long enough to not to fit in navigation title then they keep it as it is with `...` at the end. I don't say you should do the same but just want to tell you.

**EDIT :** To do it right to left :

```
- (void)animateLabel:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    int labelSize = label.text.length; 
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", [label.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, labelSize - 1)], [label.text characterAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Comment: label.length;   no property like this

Comment: i will save the text to NSString and find the length and i will copy that text to uilabel..thanks akash

Comment: @user2439088 No need to copy in separate NSString. See my edited code.

Comment: 100 Points on that Answer Mate! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is moving the UILabel to one point and back again, why don't you use the completion to call another animation?